# Decode input stream from UTF-8 and write that in log file

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have xml file which will come with UTF-8 encoding as a input stream to my code and i need to write that file to the log file. Below is the code that i tried but that does not work, it prints all the encoded fields.

Sending encoded input stream as

```
FileOutputStream streamer = new FileOutputStream(filename);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(streamer, "UTF-8");
```

**writer** output stream is fed to the below code as **this.encodedInputStream**

**Code**

```
    InputStreamReader decodedInputStream = new InputStreamReader(this.encodedInputStream , StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(decodedInputStream);
    String readLine = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      while ((readLine = reader.readLine())!=null){
readLine = URLDecoder.decode(readLine, "UTF-8");
        builder.append(readLine);
      }
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Exception while logging WSCallMFE", e);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    log.info(result);
```

Above code prints the below values

```
%3Cprop%3E%3Cjavavendor%3ETest+Test%3C%2Fjavavendor%3E%0A%3Cdrive%3EC%3A%3C%2Fdrive
```

Expected result

```
<prop><java.vendor>Test Test</java.vendor>
<drive>C:</drive>
```

If i pass the xml notepad file directly as input stream to **this.encodedInputStream**, then it gives the expected output.
Any idea how can i convert the whole encoded file and get rid of encoded characters?

Comment: What does the original input file contain? It looks like URL encoding not UTF-8.

Comment: It is an XML file. And it is using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Just because the XML file itself uses UTF-8 doesn't mean that text inside it couldn't also be URL-encoded. URL encoding is basically "layered on top" of UTF-8 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like to be encoded with some [URL Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). Here you can use [`URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) from `java.net` to get rid of these encoded content:

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%3Cprop%3E%3Cjavavendor%3ETest+Test%3C%2Fjavavendor%3E%0A%3Cdrive%3EC%3A%3C%2Fdrive\r\n", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

**Output:**

```
<prop><javavendor>Test Test</javavendor>
<drive>C:</drive
```

Comment: It is a Xml file not URL. So can we use URL decoder to decode the whole xml?

Comment: I was able to fix the code using URLDecoder.decode. But the result is not adding "." while decoding. Update the question with the code.

Comment: @SSharma2203 There is not dot in your same String also.